# Diplomatic word to express having difficulty or finding it unpleasant working with someone.

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, politeness

I'm filling out a feedback form for a senior colleague who I've been working with, I want say something like

> Last year I had some difficulty working with John, but since the start of the year he's given me more room to breathe and allowed me to work with more autonomy.

Comment: The word "challenges" would work well, but you might phrase it collectively.  "Last year John and I had some challenges working together, but since the start of the year..."

Answer (score 2):

I would say,

> Last year I found it challenging to work with John, but since the first of the year, I've felt I had more autonomy, and the working relationship between John and me seems more beneficial to the two of us, and to the company.

I think this is a stronger way to state it because it does not make it seem that it is your supervisor's fault. The likelyhood is one of two things: the other people in the company already know how difficult John is to work with, so you need not specify that fact. Further, others may see that some of the problem is on your end, not John's. In addition, by keeping it as an "I" statement (I've felt more autonomy), as contrasted with what John has done, you are showing your strengths without seeming undermine John.

This is not to say John may not be deserving of the way you wrote it originally, but I think the alternative I provided reflects gets the same message across and holds you in a better light at the same time.